# Winzip - how to include only top level folder/exclude all subcontents?

Tags: winzip, exclude

I have a question for winzip command line. I have a mapped network drive and I want to add the sdcard directory

My mapped network drive Z:\sdcard\ has alot of files and folders within it. But how can I use winzip command line to ONLY add the sdcard\ folder and skip everything else under it?

I have tried to use a exclude list .txt file with "Z:\sdcard*" as an entry but this is supposed to mean everything under sdcard\ folder not including the sdcard\ folder itself but this seems to exclude the entire folder and its contents. What should I do ?

This is the syntax I am using:
WZZIP -a -yx -e0 -r -P -x@"C:\users\xxx\Downloads\exclude list for winzip.txt" winziptest.zip "Z:\sdcard"

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion?